# Redirecting to action and invoking `tel:123` programmatically and `mailto:abc@def.com` by controller's action on a clients side in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, hyperlink, href

When we click on link `<a href="tel:123">123</a>` the default calling application for our system will call this number.

Obviously we can add this link to a Razor view and then click it. But what if I want to make this link not only call by default calling application like Skype but also redirect to the other action?

I have done this:

- Created a pretty calling button by: `<p>@Html.ActionLink("Call Cell Phone", "Call", new { id = Model.Id, number = Model.CellNumber }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>` it goes to the `Call` action and we pass id of person we call and number of the person.

[image]

- Added the call action where I get rid of dashes and whitespaces in phone number then use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to invoke call:

---

```
public string formatPhoneNumber(string number) {
                Regex rgx = new Regex("[^0-9]");
                return rgx.Replace(number, "");
            }

        public ActionResult Call(int id, string number) {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            string formattedNumber = "tel:+48" + formatPhoneNumber(number);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NUMBER " + formattedNumber);
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = formattedNumber;
                proc.Start();
                Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", new Person { Id = id });
            }
```

**And it works,** Skype tries to call someone on my computer. My problem is that it works in debug mode, but when I publish it to Windows Azure then I think `proc.Start();` will be invoked on the server not client side and this will stop working.

So how to click `tel:12312341` link on clients side from controller?

EDIT: I do not ask about Skype or any other caller/dialer program. I ask about programatically clicking `tel:...` link.

**NOTE:** I will have full control of every user's devices because every device will be mine(used by employee)  so I can install any program on client side. If it helps in any way.

Comment: You are right that the process will run on the server, so this is the wrong approach to doing the call from the client computer. You can't reliably invoke the `tel:` link and do a redirect in the client script at the same time, because one will cancel the other. You would need to use a timer, so that one happens first, then the other after a while.

Comment: @Guffa Should this timer be in the view or in the controller? Could you make a simple demo in the answer without all the trimming of the number. The number is in the `Model.Number` in the view. I am still very new to the ASP .NET MVC.

Comment: @Guffa  Oh t his application will be used only by few people(not public) and if there is a direct way to invoke processes on the clients computers it would be great.

Comment: Neither. You would do this in client script. You can't invoke the `tel:` link from the server side.

Comment: @Guffa I would start bounty but my question is fresh. I assume that you were referring to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd410060(v=vs.100).aspx . If you have a minute to show how this script would look like and how to invoke it from view it would be great. Anyways, THANK you.

Comment: The point is that you wouldn't invoke it from the view at all. You would use Javascript to do this, not server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a javascript file with the following code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    window.location.replace("tel:123-456-789");
}
```

You're gonna want two views.

1) The view you currently have with the button saying "Call Cell"
2) A view that includes the javascript file.

The button in View 1 should be an action link to the action in your controller.

Within the action, you need to add the code that you want to do prior to calling the cell phone.

At the end of the Action, return the view that's including the javascript file and the link should be called, intiating the phone call.

Comment: The first paragraph of your answer is in last paragraph of my question. I do not want run precisely Skype but just invoke link of type `tel:123-456-789`. I edited question to state it more directly.

Comment: Even In bounty comment I asked about `tel:` link not Skype.

Comment: `window.location.replace("tel:123-456-789");` If you want to automatically call it. There's no way you can alter the request though unless you make it so the link takes you to an action and the action does what you want then displays a view with the javascript above so it's the last thing that's done.

Comment: Where I should write this `window.location...` View? Controller? Script? Where is object `window`?

Comment: It would go in a javascript file or in your view. Depends how fussy you are about where you place your javascript. Just make sure the view is returned AFTER you do what it is your want to do in the action.

Comment: Is `window.location.replace("tel:123-456-789");` whole code in java script file? I had minor expierience with java script in the past. You call there `window`` which has to be passed somehow to java script from C# code what object is it?  Could you complete your answer how the script would look like and how to call it from controller. That is all I look for.

Comment: Edited my answer to describe it a little better :)

Comment: Ok the only last thing is how to run this script in c# code?

Comment: Might be best to start a new question for that and I'll look out for it. Javascript would run as intended in your View, along side your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers are purposely limited to sandbox environment to restrict the sort of access web sites have to client systems.  If any website could selectively invoke any program on a client PC, it would be a massive security hole.

The ONLY way to execute an application client side is through a carefully designed ActiveX control made for the specific application which is to be executed.  It just so happens that Skype installs this sort of ActiveX control, which intercepts the `tel:` links in a browser to launch the Skype client locally.

It may be possible to write a JavaScript function which is able to execute a very specific program on a client machine, a la `new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");`, assuming that you know exactly the command line to execute the process with, that the location of the executable is identical on every client machine, the clients have loose restrictions on unsigned ActiveX controls (major security issue), and the users don't choose to use a non ActiveX compatible browser.

Bottom line, it's not a trivial process to create a website which launches a client application.

Comment: I do not know what mistake I have made in problem's description. I do NOT want to run any application on client side. It is not the case. I don't ask about Skype.

I just want to invoke link `tel:...` programatically so user does not have to click it. I don't care what application is bonded to `tel:` links on client's side.

Comment: and this is exactly the kind of thing that is a client control process.  you cannot "automate" your client system from the server.

Comment: perhaps your entire question is off from what you are trying to do, but here you show a server side script which is executing a client side program.  This only works because the client and the server are the same machine.  Skype uses unique href tags because user interaction is required, and from what has been said on the question so far, you are either trying to execute something other than Skype, or you are trying to change how the Skype ActiveX control works, neither of which are feasible.

Comment: " This only works because the client and the server are the same machine." I wrote this in question. I know that. I do not ask about Skype. I ask how to progrmatically click `tel:` or `mailto:` link. Please forget about existance of Skype.

Comment: Skype or any other program, it doesn't matter.  There is no reasonable way to click a link on a user's behalf, and no easy way for a server action to trigger a client activity.